# Clojure example that works with protobuf

Tags: clojure, protocol-buffers

MODIFIED. This code now works.

I am trying to follow the example here:

https://github.com/flatland/clojure-protobuf

I created a new project thus:

```
lein new protobuf
```

Changing directory into protobuf, I added inside /resources/proto/ the example.proto file with these contents:

```
option java_package = "com.example";

package Example;

message Person {
   required int32  id    = 1;
   required string name  = 2;
   optional string email = 3;
   repeated string likes = 4;
}
```

My project file looks like this. The only difference from the example in the url above is that I modified to 1.5.1.

```
(defproject org.flatland/protobuf "0.8.2-SNAPSHOT"
 :description "Clojure-protobuf provides a clojure interface to Google's protocol buffers."
 :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
 :url "https://github.com/flatland/clojure-protobuf"
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
             [org.flatland/protobuf "0.7.1"] 
             [org.flatland/useful "0.11.1"]
             [org.flatland/schematic "0.1.2"]
             [org.flatland/io "0.3.0"]
             [ordered-collections "0.4.2"]]
 :plugins [[lein-protobuf "0.1.1"]]
 :aliases {"testall" ["with-profile" "dev,default:dev,1.3,default:dev,1.5,default" "test"]}
 :profiles {:1.3 {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]}
         :1.5 {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.0-master-SNAPSHOT"]]}
         :dev {:dependencies [[gloss "0.2.2"]]}}
 :repositories {"sonatype-snapshots" {:url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
                                   :snapshots true
                                   :releases {:checksum :fail :update :always}}}
 :checksum-deps true
 :java-source-paths ["src"])
```

I then did a

```
lein protobuf
```

Now I entered the REPL

```
lein repl
```

I tried the first command:

```
(use 'flatland.protobuf.core)
```

Then I tried the next line

```
(import com.example.Example$Person)
```

Then the rest of the example works fine.

Comment: Dependency in the [README](https://github.com/flatland/clojure-protobuf#getting-started) is specified as `[org.flatland/protobuf "0.7.1"]`. Is there any reason why you are using `[protobuf "0.6.2"]`?

Comment: You are also missing the inclusion of the leiningen plugin `[lein-protobuf "0.1.1"]` and the compilation of the `.proto` file by using this plugin `lein protobuf`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. See the changes I made above to make it clearer. I made all your suggestions to the project. I also modified the .proto file. I am not sure about your lein protobuf suggestion I was always doing that. Now (use 'flatland.protobuf.core) works but I still get an error when I do (import Example$Person)

Comment: `import` simply resolves the named Java class. It appears as if you've directed protobuf to generate Java classes under the package `com.example`. Try `(import com.example.Example$Person)` instead.

Comment: Ok I think it works! I will post all the corrections soon! Thanks!

Comment: if you figured this out, why not add it as an answer & mark it so?

Comment: @user1676605 please change the question back to being a question and add an answer with the corrections so others can learn from what you have learned :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`clojusc/protobuf`](https://github.com/clojusc/protobuf) is a better maintained fork. Project readme contains a straightforward protobuf example. It shows how to use the `protoc` compiler and `java` interop clearly.